# How much difference does hot vs cold air make with regards to an Aprilaire 600 furnace humidifier evaporation rate?

Tags: furnace, humidity, humidifier

If I run the humidifier only when the heat is on, I get good evaporation.  However, I want to consider also running it with just the fan running because our furnace doesn't run all that often.  Will I still achieve reasonable evaporation in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the following tests with an ambient temperature of approximately 70 degrees F.  I measured the (hot) water flowing into the humidifier and the water flowing out of the drain to calculate the % evaporation in each case (there is a reasonable margin of error).

1. Furnace running in low stage.  Approximate air temperature coming from register is 120 degrees F.  Humidity was 25% @ 70F.  Measured 24% evaporation rate.
2. Furnace is off, fan running on low setting. Approximate air tempertaure coming from register is 70 degrees F.   Humidity was 25% @ 70F. Measured 19% evaporation rate.
3. Same setup as 2, but humidity was ~32% @ 70F.  Measured 14% evaporation rate.

Unfortunately, this indicates a large amount of water being wasted, especially with the heat off.  Aprilaire advertises that it uses 3 gallons per hour with a 0.7 gallon/hour evaporation rate (24%), which matches with my test for #1.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this as a comment on KyleL's response, but I don't have the rep to do so yet.  You should check to see if your humidifier is fed with hot or cold water.  A hot water feed will have an increased rate of evaporation over a cold water feed.  If your humidifier is connected to a cold water feed, switching it to hot may fix your problem.

Comment: It's hot water.  Sorry this wasn't super clear in the original answer.